# Getting seleted menu item

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qmenu

I am implementing run time menu on a button(QPushButton) in my app user has to make choice between ftp and http when he click on upload button.

```
QMenu menu(this); 
menu.addAction("ftp");
menu.addAction("http");
ui.mUploadBtn->setMenu(&menu);
ui.mUploadBtn->showMenu();
```

My ques is that how could i know which selection user selected or is their any function to get that.

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to catch the result of a menu is to do this :

```
 QAction* action = menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
```

Then you can use

```
action->text()==QString("ftp")
```

To know if the user clicked on  "FTP".

So as said by Frank Osterfeld in the comments, you can also create a slot in you class, and connect menu trigger action signal to it :

```
connect(&menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT( sl_OnMenuTriggered(QAction* )));

void sl_OnMenuTriggered(QAction* _action)
{
if(_action->text()=="ftp") ...
}
```

This is the "non blocking" way.

Comment: Or connect to QMenu::triggered(QAction*), in case you want to use showMenu() or some other non-blocking way of showing the menu.

Comment: menu.exec() not showing menu at right location after pressing on upload button it shows menu on left top corner of screen

Comment: Ok, you can use the second way I introduced in my response, or menu.exec(QCursor::pos());

Comment: sorry i  missed to place &menu in connect

Comment: Ok.. its corrected, I didn't see it when I approved the edition :)